# Couchbase 3.0.1 and .NET SDK 2.0 ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: .net, couchbase

I have this code, that after running few iterations gives the following error.
Any idea?

I am using Couchbase 3.0.1 and .NET SDK 2.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Couchbase;
using Couchbase.Core;

namespace CouchTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var s = new Stopwatch();

            s.Start();

            var result = Parallel.For(0, 10000, ctr =>
            {
                var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                CouchbaseClient.Instance.Bucket.Insert(id, id, ReplicateTo.Zero, PersistTo.One);

            });


            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
            Console.Read();
        }

    }


    [Serializable]
    public sealed class CouchbaseClient
    {

        public static readonly CouchbaseClient Instance = new CouchbaseClient();

        public IBucket Bucket;

        private CouchbaseClient()
        {
            Bucket = new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase").OpenBucket("default");
        }
    }
}
```

The parallel loop does run randomly 20-30 times before the exception.

The error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---
>
> > System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateE xception: One or more errors occurred. --->
> >     System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a
> >     location within the buffer. Parameter name: bytes    at
> >     System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32
> >     count)
>
> at Couchbase.IO.Converters.AutoByteConverter.ToString(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 of fset, Int32 length) in
>   c:\jenkins\workspace-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchb
>   ase\IO\Converters\AutoByteConverter.cs:line 83    at
>   Couchbase.IO.Operations.Observe.GetValue() in
>   c:\jenkins\workspace-net2\co
>   uchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\IO\Operations\Observe.cs:line 49
>   at Couchbase.IO.Operations.OperationBase`1.GetResult() in
>   c:\jenkins\workspac
>   e-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\IO\Operations\OperationBase'.cs:line
>   2 84    at Couchbase.Core.Server.Send[T](IOperation`1 operation) in
>   c:\jenkins\worksp
>   ace-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\Core\Server.cs:line 97
>   at
>   Couchbase.Core.Buckets.KeyObserver.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__10
>   () in
>   c:\jenkins\workspace-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\Core\Buckets\
>   KeyObserver.cs:line 204    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
>   ification(Task task)    at
>   Couchbase.Core.Buckets.KeyObserver.<CheckReplica>d__14.MoveNext() in
>   c:\je
>   nkins\workspace-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\Core\Buckets\KeyObserver
>   .cs:line 0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32
>   millisecondsTimeou t, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Couchbase.Core.Buckets.KeyObserver.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Observe>b__1(Observ
>   eParams p) in
>   c:\jenkins\workspace-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\Core\
>   Buckets\KeyObserver.cs:line 162    at
>   Couchbase.Core.Buckets.KeyObserver.<ObserveEvery>d__18.MoveNext() in
>   c:\je
>   nkins\workspace-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\Core\Buckets\KeyObserver
>   .cs:line 233    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceled Exceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationTo ken cancellationToken)    at
>   Couchbase.Core.Buckets.KeyObserver.Observe(String key, UInt64 cas,
>   Boolean  deletion, ReplicateTo replicateTo, PersistTo persistTo) in
>   c:\jenkins\workspace
>   -net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\Core\Buckets\KeyObserver.cs:line
>   169    at Couchbase.CouchbaseBucket.Observe(String key, UInt64 cas,
>   Boolean deletion , ReplicateTo replicateTo, PersistTo persistTo) in
>   c:\jenkins\workspace-net2\cou
>   chbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\CouchbaseBucket.cs:line 281    at
>   Couchbase.CouchbaseBucket.SendWithDurability[T](IOperation`1
>   operation, Bo olean deletion, ReplicateTo replicateTo, PersistTo
>   persistTo) in c:\jenkins\work
>   space-net2\couchbase-net-client\Src\Couchbase\CouchbaseBucket.cs:line
>   299    at Couchbase.CouchbaseBucket.Insert[T](String key, T value,
>   ReplicateTo repli cateTo, PersistTo persistTo) in
>   c:\jenkins\workspace-net2\couchbase-net-client\S
>   rc\Couchbase\CouchbaseBucket.cs:line 832    at
>   CouchTest2.Program.b__0(Int32 ctr)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b_
>   _10(Object param0)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceled Exceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationTo ken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int 32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWit hState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int32
>   fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive , Action`1 body)    at
>   CouchTest2.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: It looks like you are using a developer preview or beta 1 version of the 2.0 SDK (CouchbaseCluster has been renamed to Cluster), can you try upgrading to Beta 2 and seeing if this resolves the issue?

Comment: @jeffrymorris I do use Beta2. If you look at the above code, you will see that it uses "Cluster". This is the link that I used to download the SDK: http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/clients/net/2.0/beta2/Couchbase-Net-Client-Beta2.zip

Comment: sorry misread the code! If you remove the replicateTo and persistTo it will probably work. Internally that overload is using "Observe" which already using async under the covers. It's likely a bug when run in a parallel loop with no MaxParallelism defined.

Comment: @jeffrymorris Thanks. About removing ReplicateTo and PersistTo, it is a problem for me, because the whole point of the test is to validate the behavior of these particular settings. I winder if I should switch to C SDK via Interop, what you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that by using an unbounded parallel loop with a default client configuration you are exhausting the connection pool and individual operations are timing out on the client (before being sent over the network). Unfortunately, there is a bug in the client that throws the AOOR when an operation times out, which will be fixed soon.

That being said, by tuning the client through the configuration I was able to get this to work as expected:

```
using (var cluster = new Cluster(new ClientConfiguration
{
    PoolConfiguration = new PoolConfiguration
    {
       MaxSize = 10,
       MinSize = 5
    }
}))
{
   var s = new Stopwatch();
   s.Start();

   using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket())
   {
        var result = Parallel.For(0, 10000, ctr =>
        {
            var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            bucket.Insert(id, id, ReplicateTo.Zero, PersistTo.One);

        });
    }
    s.Stop();
 }
```

Note that default configuration creates a connection pool with two TCP connections, which can quickly be exhausted. In which case each thread will try up to 5 times (by default) to acquire a connection. If it cannot, the operation will fail with a ClientError since the request never made to the network. You can tune the number iterations that a thread will try to acquire a connection by increasing the PoolConfiguration.MaxAcquireIterationCount value as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is another thing I found out. While incorporating the above example into my code, I have discovered that these exact settings are already specified in the config section. Aren't these interchangeable, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is the config '  <couchbaseClients>
    <couchbase useSsl="false">
      <servers>
        <add uri="http://192.168.0.4:8091/pools"></add>
        <add uri="http://192.168.0.5:8091/pools"></add>
        <add uri="http://192.168.0.6:8091/pools"></add>
      </servers>
      <buckets>
        <add name="default" useSsl="false" password="">
          <connectionPool name="custom" maxSize="10" minSize="5"></connectionPool>
        </add>
      </buckets>
    </couchbase>
  </couchbaseClients>'

Comment: Right, but in my case it wasn't working, as I had these setting configured from the beginning.

Comment: @realPro -hmm, could be a bug in the app.config portion. Also, TPL performance depends upon the hardware it's running on, so code that works fine on my machine, may fail on another. There is a bug that is causing the code to fail, so if your getting enough performance, you'll eventually hit it. You can also try bumping those values even higher. Also, the bug is fixed in github, so you can pull from there to validate.

Comment: Getting the latest git commit solved the issue. Thanks!